# eve-swagger ImportError: cannot import name add_documentation

Tags: python-2.7, swagger, eve

I'm using for the first time eve-swagger and I tried to execute the example provided in the README.rst file with the error message:
ImportError: cannot import name add_documentation

I tried to grep add_documentation in the repository and seems to be not defined.

Is this function defined in other version of eve-swagger?
How can I update elements in the documentation at run-time?

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`add_documentation` is on 0.0.5 which is still in development ([changelog](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve-swagger/blob/master/CHANGES)). If you installed from PyPI (`pip install eve-swagger`) then you are on v0.0.4, which has no `add_documentation` available.

Either you wait for 0.0.5 to go live, or you install the development version, which you can do with:

`pip install git+https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve-swagger`